# How to get image from this BBC feed using Python and Universal Feed Parser

Tags: python, feed, feedparser

I am using this feed http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml and want to get all media:thumbnail entries. I.e. all images

```
   import feedparser
   d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml')
   e = d['entries'][0]
   print e.media_thumbnail ## this returns ''
```

The entry has this in the rss:

```
      media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/50560000/jpg/_50560468_50557389.jpg"
      media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/50581000/jpg/_50581208_010904244-1.jpg"
```

So, the info is there, but how can I get it?

(I am using the latest feedparser version feedparser.**version** -> '4.2-pre-294-svn')

Comment: What licence are the photos available under?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the latest SVN r354 I got this working:

```
>>> e = d['entries'][0]
>>> print e["media_thumbnail"][0]["url"]
http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/50560000/jpg/_50560468_50557389.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Where do I get this r345 from? It is not here: http://nightly.feedparser.org/dist/ or at Google Code https://code.google.com/p/feedparser/downloads/list

Comment: Directly download `feedparser.py` from http://feedparser.googlecode.com/svn-history/r354/trunk/feedparser/feedparser.py

Answer (score 0):

This works just as well especially if you want the picture for each article in the feed:

```
d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml')
for entry in d.entries:
    print(entry.media_thumbnail)
```